# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - But I did Initialize it?

Tags: c#

I came a cross some difficulty with my object.
Im trying to have an array of object (Question) that I've created:

```
public class Question
{
    public int id = 0;
    public string question = string.Empty;

    public string a1 = string.Empty;
    public string a2 = string.Empty;
    public string a3 = string.Empty;
    public string a4 = string.Empty;

    public int Tanswer = 0;

}
```

and Now Im trying to set some values in it like this :

```
Question[] arr = new Question[4];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    bool ok = false;

    while (i < 3)
    {
        temp = rnd.Next(0, Int32.Parse(dt_count.Rows[0][0].ToString()) - 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            arr[j].id = Int32.Parse(dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][0].ToString());  // ID
            arr[j].question = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][1].ToString();  // Question
            arr[j].a1 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][2].ToString();  // A1
            arr[j].a2 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][3].ToString();   // A2
            arr[j].a3 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][4].ToString();  // A3
            arr[j].a4 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][5].ToString();  // A4
            arr[j].Tanswer = Int32.Parse(dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][6].ToString());  // True Answer (int).

            if (arr[j].id != temp)
            {
                ok = true;

            }
        }

        if (ok)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

and its write an error for some reason, like I've been never initialize it :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

but I did wrote the :

```
Question[] arr = new Question[4];
```

so I wonder whats the problem is ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've initialised `arr` as a new array, but all of its elements are still null. You need to initialise each item before you access it:

```
arr[j] = new Question();
arr[j].id = Int32.Parse(dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][0].ToString());
...
```

Comment: This is right.this is exactly what I wanted to explain in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The array you created is filled with nulls, not Question instances.

> ```
> arr[0] = new Question();
> arr[1] = new Question();
> arr[2] = new Question();
> arr[3] = new Question();
> ```

This would do the trick.

Comment: It's not an empty array, it's an array in which every element is `null`. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You must create each object of the array.

```
Question[] arr = new Question[4];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    bool ok = false;

    while (i < 3)
    {
        temp = rnd.Next(0, Int32.Parse(dt_count.Rows[0][0].ToString()) - 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
        {
            arr[j] = new Question();
            arr[j].id = Int32.Parse(dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][0].ToString());  // ID
            arr[j].question = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][1].ToString();  // Question
            arr[j].a1 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][2].ToString();  // A1
            arr[j].a2 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][3].ToString();   // A2
            arr[j].a3 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][4].ToString();  // A3
            arr[j].a4 = dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][5].ToString();  // A4
            arr[j].Tanswer = Int32.Parse(dt_q_notMust.Rows[temp][6].ToString());  // True Answer (int).

            if (arr[j].id != temp)
            {
                ok = true;

            }
        }

        if (ok)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have initialized the array (indeed, you allocated some memory for 4 items) but not the objects within the array. I have no visual studio right now to try the solution, but you may try to initialize the array with initialized objects.

Answer (score 0):

So here you just create an 'Array' instance which can contain the instances of the class 'Question'. But you haven't created any instance of 'Question'.

You can add the following line:

```
arr[j] = new Question();
```

before setting property values.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, whilst you've initialized the array you haven't initialized the items within the `Array`. If it makes more sense for a `Question` to be treated as a value-type you could define it as a `struct` rather than a `class`, that way initializing the `Array` alone would suffice and you could access the items within it to set their properties as you wish without having to initialize the items. If you wanted to keep `Question` as a class however, you could wrap the `Array` in a class that lazily initializes the items when they're accessed.

```
public class SelfInitializingArray<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : class
{
    private Func<T> _builder;
    private T[] _items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the SelfInitializingArray class.
    /// </summary>
    public SelfInitializingArray(int size, Func<T> builder)
    {
        _builder = builder;
        _items = new T[size];
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return ItemOrDefaultAtIndex(i);
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemOrDefaultAtIndex(index);
        }
        set
        {
            _items[index] = value;
        }
    }

    private T ItemOrDefaultAtIndex(int index)
    {
        if (_items[index] == null)
            _items[index] = _builder();

        return _items[index];
    }
}
```

Then you can use this as follows:

```
var questions = new SelfInitializingArray<Question>(4, () => new Question());

questions[0].Id = 12345; //etc.
```